# Flutter app freezes when navigating away from news api screen and returning

Tags: flutter

My news api works well except for when I navigate to another screen and then it freezes on return. I've noticed a pattern in that it works then when you navigate to another screen and go back it freezes but then if you go to a different screen again and return, it works again. So after every other time you return to the screen it works.

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6794): The following assertion was thrown building ArticleTile(dirty):
I/flutter ( 6794): A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

How would I solve this?

```
Container(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: articles.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return ArticleTile(
                                    imageUrl: articles[index].urlToImage,
                                    title: articles[index].title,
                                    desc: articles[index].description,
                                    url: articles[index].url,
```

```
body: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: widget.articleUrl,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  }),
```

```
 return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ArticleView(
              articleUrl: url,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
```

```
class _BottomNavBarControllerState extends State<BottomNavBarController> {
  final List<Widget> pages = [
    const NewsHome(
      key: const PageStorageKey('Page1'),
    ),
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_selectedIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
```